# tabbed popup window for Arcgis Javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Anyone know examples of a tabbed popup window for Arcgis for javascript, NOT an infowindow? If you could point me in the the right direction it would help.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652182/pop-up-with-tab-container

I would just use a dojo dialog window and format the data however you want inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want to use a [dijit.layout.TabContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html) most likely. Or [bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) depending on your preferences. If you don't want to use the info window then you would

1. connect to the map click event
2. xhr the identify
3. format the results into one of those types of containers.